# Listview and activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Friends, I click an item in listview row and it leads to another activity.
From that activity I press the back button. That back button should do an update in listview row and lead back to the listview row from where I clicked. How to do that? It is similar to that in facebook in your mobile app. You post a comment and press back button it reaches the row from where the comment activity started and then the row is updated as well.

Comment: please give us code. But i think you should update listview on onStart. See more about life cycle android. When you move to another activity your last activity activate onStop and when you back it activate onStart.

Comment: post here what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use it [listview](https://github.com/AlicanAkyol/AndroidHelp/blob/master/Listview/app/src/main/java/com/alican/listview/MainActivity.java)
But you should change onclick event. And also you should change list_values array what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StartActivityForResult (in onItemClick) and react by onActivityResult.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file ad:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourClassName"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```